# Constructed value not found in switch statement

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    //variables
    String name = "";
    String advisor;
    String strSelection;
    int iSelection;
    String studentID;
    String concentration;
    String strHours;
    int iHours = 0;
    String strMajorSheet;
    boolean majorSheet = false;
    String strIntent;       //holds JOptionPane input for intent to graduate
    boolean intent = false; //intent to graduate
    boolean blnReq = false; //requirements met
    String classification;  //holds classification of advisee
    String strClear;    //clear to graduate
    boolean blnEmpty ;  //empty?
    blnEmpty = name.isEmpty();  //no advisee in system
    String strUpdate;   //catches option 2
    int iCount = 0; //# of advisees entered
    Advisee a1, a2, a3;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "          Welcome to the Advising Manager!\n--------Created by Mason Bailey and Zach Latture--------","Message",1);
    advisor = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "\tWhat is the advisor's name?", "Input", 3);
    strSelection = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,  "~~Please make a selection from the menu below~~" +
                                                    "\n\n\n1.Add a new advisee" +
                                                    "\n2.Update an advisee's information" +
                                                    "\n\n\n3.Display all advisees" +
                                                    "\n4.Display advisees who are cleared to graduate" +
                                                    "\n5.Exit:" +
                                                    "\n\n\n\n\nWhat is your selection", "Input", 3);
    iSelection = Integer.parseInt(strSelection);
    switch(iSelection)
    {
        case 1:
                name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Name: ", "Advisee",3);
                studentID = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Student ID: ", "Advisee",3);
                concentration = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Concentration: ", "Advisee",3);
                strHours = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Hours Completed: ", "Advisee",3);
                strMajorSheet = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Have you filed your major sheet? (True/False)", "Advisee",3);
                    if(strMajorSheet.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
                    {
                        majorSheet = true;
                    }   //end if
                strIntent = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Do you intend to graduate? (True/False)", "Advisee",3);
                    if(strIntent.equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
                    {
                        intent = true;
                    }   //end if
                    iCount++;
                    switch(iCount)
                    {
                        case 1:
                                a1 = new Advisee(name,studentID,concentration,iHours,advisor,majorSheet,intent);
                        break;
                        case 2:
                                a2 = new Advisee(name,studentID,concentration,iHours,advisor,majorSheet,intent);
                                break;
                        case 3:
                                a3 = new Advisee(name,studentID,concentration,iHours,advisor,majorSheet,intent);
                        break;
                    }   
        break;

        case 2:
                if(blnEmpty = true)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"There are no advisees in the system yet");
                }   //end if
                switch(iCount)
                {
                    case 1:
                            strUpdate = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "***Please select which advisee's information you need to update***" + a1.getName,"Input",3);
                }//end switch
    }//end switch

}//end main
```

in the above code, the switch(iCount) statement located in case 1 for switch(iSelection) creates an advisee using a constructor. in the switch(iCount) found in  case 2 of switch(iSelection) i need to display the name of the advisee referenced a1. when i do so, a1 is not found. case 2 can only be ran after everything in case 1 has been entered, therefore a1 already be defined. How can i code this (using relatively basic strategies) so that i can display the name from a1 to be displayed? I'm relatively new to coding, any input will be greatly appreciated. thank you for your time.

Comment: Declaring your Advisee vars inside the switch statement means that they're only accessible between the enclosing `{}` characters.  Declare the variables at a scope (level of `{}` brackets) where they will be accessible when you need them.  To keep the compiler from complaining (validly) about "uninitialized variable" initialize them with `null` where you declare them.

Comment: (But I suspect you have other problems with this code as well.)

Comment: this runs once and terminates is it not? so state won't be preserved between different execution runs. Can you tel us what you want to achieve here? Specifically you show a dialog and ask for input and process it and the program terminates. There is no loop here.

Comment: Your Advisee vars are not initialized to `null`, meaning you will not be able to access them later because you will get an "uninitialized variable" error.  Initialize them -- `Advisee a1 = null;`.

Comment: And if you're getting a compile error, please post it (quote it exactly!) and indicate what line it refers to.  Just saying "it doesn't work" is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry for writing this as answer, but I don't have enough reputation to write a comment...

```
 // ...

 case 2:
            if(blnEmpty = true) {
                // ..
            }

// ...
```

Note that `if(blnEmpty = true)` is an assignment. It will always be true! To check whether something is true use `==`. It's a tip for beginners to always use `true == something` because `true = something` will not compile.

It might not be main problem in your question but it still is a big problem (it'll always claim: There are no advisees in the system yet. That leads to false conclusions).

Comment: Good catch!  I don't have the attention span to suss out stuff like that in others' code.

Answer (score -1):

Declare Advisee variables at a higher scope say at class scope. This will make them accessible at a much broader regions of the code.

```
class SomeClass {
Advisee a1, a2, a3;
```

Then in `switch(iCount)` statement in first case, just use the above variables as

```
a1 = new Advisee(name,studentID,concentration,iHours,advisor,majorSheet,intent);
                        break;
                        case 2:
a2 = new Advisee(name,studentID,concentration,iHours,advisor,majorSheet,intent);
                                break;
                        case 3:
a3 = new Advisee(name,studentID,concentration,iHours,advisor,majorSheet,intent);
                        break;
```

Comment: The vars should not be made class scope unless they are intended to become a part of the object's persistent state.  Simply putting them there for the convenience of not having to null them is a bad idea.

Comment: @HotLicks I idea of putting them at class scope was not to avoid `null`. I might not have understood what you said by that anyway. The reason it is at class scope is to be keep state persistent across different behaviour invocations - two different switch invocations at two different times. Please reverse your down vote just so that the question is being asked by a learner and he might get the wrong idea of what i am saying.

Comment: I downvoted specifically because he *is* a newbie, and resorting to class scope at the first sign of difficulty is a bad habit to learn.

Comment: Yes, I'm obviously bad at coding. But I'm here to learn. I set them all to null, but how do i get the information of the updated variables into the first case of the second switch statement?

Comment: @user2909717 can you post what you have done as an update to the question?

Comment: Put the vars outside your loop.

Comment: I did what you stated in your post. 
I added Advisee a1, a2, a3; to main then a1 = new Advisee(name,studentID,concentration,iHours,advisor,majorSheet,intent);

to the switch


                        break;
                        case 2:
a2 = new Advisee(name,studentID,concentration,iHours,advisor,majorSheet,intent);
                                break;
                        case 3:
a3 = new Advisee(name,studentID,concentration,iHours,advisor,majorSheet,intent);
                        break;

Comment: @user2909717 BTW you have 3 switch statements, and the problem vars are actually inside the second, so getting them to the second switch statement seems moot.

Comment: Oh sorry. After everything that was said I still can't get a1 to be found in my third switch statement

Comment: @user2909717 (You probably need to reformat/reindent your code nicely, with all the `}` chars lining up with their associated `{` characters, so you can tell what you're doing.)

Comment: @user2909717 You might have to post your code which includes `main` here i guess to help you more.

Comment: @user2909717 - Go back and edit your question, inserting the entire method listing.